# Get only the first value from std::cin

Tags: c++

When reading some input from `std::cin` I want to allow only a single numeric entry. So given the code

```
float n = 0;
std::cin >> n;
```

how would I then identify the case where the user input something like `1 2 3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getline` and `istringstream` and run `while` loop to count number of integers entered:

```
string line;
getline(cin, line);
int x, cnt = 0;
istringstream iss(line);
while(iss >> x){
    cnt++;
}
```

`cnt` would be `3` for `1 2 3`.